# I want to know the for loop construction with respect to arrays

Tags: php, for-loop

How to reindex this array after unsetting the array:

```
echo "before deleting:<br>";
$countries[] = "Japan";
$countries[] = "Korea";
$countries[] = "china";

echo $a  = count($countries);
echo "<br>";

for($i= 0;$i < $a; $i++)
{
    echo "$countries[$i]<br>";
}

unset($countries[1]);
echo "<br>";
```

After unset function, the count shows 2 but the 2nd 
country name china is not echoed with the loop below.

```
echo "<hr>After deleting:<br>";
echo $a = count($countries);
echo "<br>";

//below is my forloop
for($i=0;$i < $a; $i++)
{
    echo "$countries[$i]<br>";
}
</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_values()` to reindex:

```
$countries = array_values($countries);
```

However just use a `foreach()` to iterate all values:

```
foreach($countries as $country) {
    echo $country;
}
```

Comment: Snap! Nice to see I'm not off track :-)

Comment: On which trip are you today :)? Coffee trip ?

Comment: @Rizier123:  Not sure yet, this today's first answer that I haven't deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for($i=0;$i < $a; $i++)
{
    echo "$countries[$i]<br>";
}
```

Use

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    echo $country . '<br>';
}
```

Foreach doesn't really care about array keys, so it'll loop through fine. If you really want to use a standard `for` loop, call this before: `$countries = array_values($countries);` and that'll effectively reset the keys of the array.

Comment: @JA21 you're very welcome. It's rare that I use standard `for` loops any more... I find `foreach` to be a lot easier and faster to type :-)

Comment: As an aside, if you need to know what the current key of the array is, you can do something like `foreach ($countries as $key => $country) { ... }`

Comment: @JA21 if you like one of the answers you've received, make sure to click the checkmark next to the answer :-)